# How to check components that is referred from anchor elements is in screen or not in Next.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

First of all, I'm making my own single page site using Next.js and Typescript. There is two sections, One of them (component 1) has my name and three anchor elements and is set as 'sticky' element please imagine navigate links, another section (component 2) has three components that the anchor elements refer to. Then I want to check whether each the components is in screen or not, according to the result I want to change an anchor element's style.

Difficult point of my situation and what I wanna ask is;

- The two sections are different child components seen from main 'page.tsx'. Then how can I pass component 2's ref information to component 1.
- Since one of component 2 is using server action which needs fetching, Is there any way to use 'useEffect' to keep checking on the compornent's view state?

Since I've been looking for a way to achieve this, I found I need to use one of them, which are;

- Intersection Observer

  - https://betterprogramming.pub/react-useinview-hook-intersection-observer-animations-and-multiple-refs-73c68a33b5b1
- useInview

  - https://www.framer.com/motion/use-in-view/

I tried to use these, though I could not figure out the way I asked above, so I'm still struggling
this problem.

Comment: Actually this question was for making my introduction web site. I made it finally and am sharing it so that people who may have the same question as me before. [This is my nav-link component's code of link](https://github.com/memorandumtk/Portfolio_Typescript/blob/main/app/ui/nav-links.tsx). You can see the result from [here](https://portfolio-typescript-omega.vercel.app/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use the `IntersectionObserver`, it allows you to detect when certain elements are visible in the viewport, this only happens when the element meets your desired intersection ratio. Here is an example for the usage:

```
"use client";

import { useEffect } from "react";

export default MyClientComponent(): JSX.Element {
  useEffect(() => {
    // get your elements
    const el1 = document.getElementById("el1");
    const el2 = document.getElementById("el2");
    const el3 = document.getElementById("el3");

    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
      // do something with the entries
    });

    // observe each element if it was found
    if (!!el1) observer.observe(el1);
    if (!!el2) observer.observe(el2);
    if (!!el3) observer.observe(el3);

    // stop observing when your component unmounts
    return () => {
      if (!!el1) observer.unobserve(el1);
      if (!!el2) observer.unobserve(el2);
      if (!!el3) observer.unobserve(el3);
    };
  }, []);

  return <>{/* Your markup here */}</>;
}
```

You also could pass a second argument to the `IntersectionObserver` constructor, the options object that allows you to configure its behavior:

- **root**: The element that is used as the viewport for checking visibility of the target. Must be the ancestor of the target. Defaults to the browser viewport if not specified or if null.
- **rootMargin**: This set of values serves to grow or shrink each side of the root element's bounding box before computing intersections, the options are similar to those of margin in CSS.
- **threshold**: Either a single number or an array of numbers which indicate at what percentage of the target's visibility the observer's callback should be executed, ranges from 0 to 1.0, where 1.0 means every pixel is visible in the viewport.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I couldn't imagine that I can define to each component even in different component file. I am able to manage an anchor element's style based on each component is in screen so far. I'll try adjust using the options of `IntersectionObserver` from now on.